Declare DATCOM parameters for a specific UAV Heron
"I'm currently attempting to use DATCOM to create the configuration for the UAV Heron. However, I'm encountering difficulties with its tail. Could you please provide assistance?"

I read "THE USAF AND CONTROL DIGITAL DATCOM, VOLUME 1, USER MANUAL" and we can use namelist HTPLNF, VTPLNF to capter the tail. However, the tail is attached to the wing, while the Heron has a slightly different structure.

